# Self-adjoint operator with respect to differentiation using a change of variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Given a polynomial space of degree $n$ and the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} x(t)\overline{y(t)} \space dt$. I need to determine if the differentiation operator $D$ is self-adjoint.

---

By the definition of self-adjoint. I need to examine $\langle D(x(t)),y(t)\rangle$ and $\langle x(t),D(y(t))\rangle$. I see that $$\langle D(x(t)),y(t)\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} D(x(t))\overline{y(t)} \space dt \tag{1}$$ and $$\langle x(t),D(y(t))\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} x(t)\overline{D(y(t))} \space dt \tag{2}$$ However, to further simply the two above, both requires a change of variable.

---

I'm not sure how this can be done with $x(t)$ as a dependent of $t$ rather than $y(t)$. That is, the standard change of variable equation describes $\int_{a}^{b} x(y(t))\frac{dy}{dt} \space dt = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} x(y) \space dy$.

I'm also not sure how a complex variable behaves under differentiation or integration, and how the whole concept changes with respect to conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration of complex-valued integral can be defined as $\displaystyle\int u+i\int v$ if $f=u+iv$, of course, the variable is real, just the value is complex. Same fashion is defined for differentiation. Of course, one can deal with vector-valued integration to prove that the aforementioned definition is consistent.

Now try to put $x(t)=it$ and $y(t)=2t$, then $x'(t)=i$, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x'(t)\overline{y(t)}dt=\int_{0}^{1}2itdt=i$, while $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\overline{x(t)}y'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}-2itdt=-i$, so $D$ is not self-adjoint.

Comment: out of curiosity, how would the change of variable work?

Comment: I think without further assumption that would be not making sense, as you see, $y(t)$ might be a complex number, but $x$ is a real variable function, what does $x(y(t))$ mean?

Comment: makes sense. Thanks